# Can I register a custom model binder somewhere other than Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, custom-model-binder

It would be handy to limit the scope of a custom model binder for just a specific controller action method or its entire controller. [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) wrote a sentence that implied alternative locations for custom model binder registration but never seemed to finish the thought:

> You can **either** put this Custom Model Binder in charge of all your DateTimes by registering it in the Global.asax

Is it possible to make these registrations at a smaller scope of the controller system? If so, is there any reason to avoid doing so outside of the Global.asax MvcApplication (e.g., performance reasons)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I was closing the tabs I opened for this question that I hadn't reached before giving up, I found [someone with an answer](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/05/21/mvc-model-binders/). You can assign a `ModelBinderAttribute` to your view models:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(SomeEditorModelModelBinder))]
public class SomeEditorModel {
    // display model goes here
}
public class SomeEditorModelModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    // custom model binder for said model goes here
}
```

While it wasn't quite what I was looking for, it is even more specific than registering it for a controller or controller method.

### Update

Thanks to Levi's comment pointing out a much better solution. If you are consuming the object with a custom model binder in an MVC action method directly, you can simply decorate that method's parameter with the `ModelBinder` property.

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod([ModelBinder(typeof(SomeEditorModelBinder))]SomeEditorModel model) { ... }
```

Comment: You can also stick [ModelBinder(typeof(...))] directly on a parameter of your action method, and the specified binder will be used for that particular parameter.